# Add key/value pair to existing secrets path in AWS secrets manager without overwriting it using boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-secrets-manager

I have this code which I'm using to put secrets in AWS secrets manager

```
class SecretsManagerSecret:
    """Encapsulates Secrets Manager functions."""
    def __init__(self, env):
        """
        :param env: Environment on which DAG is running
        """
        self.secretsmanager_client = boto3.client("secretsmanager", region_name="us-east-1")
        self.env = env
        self.name = None

    def put_value(self, secret_value, stages=None):

        if self.name is None:
            raise ValueError("Secret Name/Path not defined")

        try:
            kwargs = {'SecretId': self.name}
            if isinstance(secret_value, str):
                kwargs['SecretString'] = secret_value
            elif isinstance(secret_value, bytes):
                kwargs['SecretBinary'] = secret_value
            if stages is not None:
                kwargs['VersionStages'] = stages
            response = self.secretsmanager_client.put_secret_value(**kwargs)
            logger.info("Value put in secret %s.", self.name)
        except ClientError:
            logger.exception("Couldn't put value in secret %s.", self.name)
            raise
        else:
            return response

secret_obj = SecretsManagerSecret("dev")
# Path of secret where multiple key value pair exists
secret_obj.name = "applications/keys/data_pipelines"
# This overwrites existing key value pairs and writes this
secret_obj.put_value('{"test":"test1235"}')
```

The issue here is when I call put_value method, it replaces all the existing key value pairs in path `applications/keys/data_pipelines` and writes `'{"test":"test1235"}'`. Is there any existing function in boto3 which can append rather than replacing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you use the [update_secret](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/secretsmanager.html#SecretsManager.Client.update_secret) method from the boto3 client for `secrets_manager`

```
client = session.client(service_name="secretsmanager")

# get the secret value first
existing_secret = client.get_secret_value(SecretId="secret_id")

# then update it with your new value
updated_secret = existing_secret.update({"UPDATE_KEY": "update_value"})

client.update_secret(SecretId="secret_id", SecretString=json.dumps(updated_secret))
```

Comment: correct, will have to fetch the secret and then update the dict to write it again. I guess using update_secret or put_secret_value won't make a difference here? I'm a little surprised though that there is no direct function to do this as AWS management console allows to add key value pairs.